# Can you use "abase oneself" positively?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, usage

Longman dictionary defines "abase yourself" as:
to behave in a way that shows you accept that someone has complete power over you

I gave an extensive lookup on the internet on the phrase. It seems to me that it has a negative nuance, but I'm not sure. Does it have a self-degrading nuance? Or can you use the phrases positively?

Thank you.

Comment: Abasement, whether of the self or others, is usually considered in Western cultures to convey a meaning of humiliation, belittlement, degradation, etc, and is usually regarded negatively. It is possible that certain cultures regard self-abasement admirable, e.g. before a social superior in very deferential societies,  or before a religious deity during worship, but this is cultural and opinion based.

Comment: Thank you for joining. So, under such a culture, can these two be interchangeable? 1: The vassals bowed down to a new emperor. 2: The vassals abased themselves in front of a new emperor.

Comment: Bowing is just lowering the head; abasement might be more, e.g. lying flat on the ground. English has an expression 'kowtow' borrowed from kau tau (Cantonese) koutou (Mandarin) The act of deep respect shown by prostration, that is, kneeling and bowing so low as to have one's head touching the ground. Widely used to show reverence for one's elders, superiors, and especially the Emperor, as well as for religious and cultural objects of worship. In modern times, usage of the kowtow has been reduced, and is only a loan word in English.

Comment: I think the natural way to say that would be _The vassals prostrated themselves before the new emperor_.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you, guys.